# Можно ли как то сохранить req.params.id до прихода нового id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

```
router.get('/serve/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const items = await serve.find({ _id: req.params.id });
 
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
  res.send(items);
});
```

Comment: данные есть в БД, они там хранятся

Comment: Дело в том что допустим я нажал на кнопку пришёл айдишник подтянулись данные из бд и мне нужно что бы они оставались при перезагрузке страницы. Но  когда перезагружаю items уже req.params.id уже undefinde

Comment: Извиняюсь не правильно задал вопрос не items сохранить а req.params.id до прихода нового айди

Comment: если этот запрос «уникален» для клиента то хранить идентификатор нужно на клиентской стороне, в локалсторадже, например, и выполнять запрос при инициализации страницы. если же запрошенный id должен быть одинаковым для все пришедших клиентов, тогда храните его в БД

Comment: как мне сохранить его в локалсторэйдж что бы при перезагрузке страницы он оттуда не пропал, а оставался там до прихода нового Id?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage